# numpy arange functon throws AttributeError: while the same code gets executed over online ide

Tags: python, numpy

This is very strange. The np.arange function throws an AttributeError while i execute the code on my computer but it works fine over the [online ide](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/spyder-ide/spyder/5.x?urlpath=/desktop).
code is very simple :
trange = np.arange(0,180,(12/60))

I am using Spyder IDE 5.0.1 and python 3.7.9

[image]

```
trange = np.arange(0,180,(12/60))
```

Comment: Looks like you or your environment have overwritten `np` with a `float` number.

Answer (score 0):

Search in your code where you have set `np = ...`

Reproducible error:

```
import numpy as np

np = 12.3

trange = np.arange(0, 180, (12/60))
```

Output:

```py
----> 5 trange = np.arange(0, 180, (12/60))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'arange'
```